# Adding TabBar Element

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, ios5

I'm doing a project in which the first view shouldn't contain any tabbar and when the view is pressed it should be moved as page flip. Then from the next page onwards tabbar items should be shown. If i'm correct i think tabbarcontroller wont help me to achieve the above. So i added a tabbar element. But how to give the button action to the tab bar items in the tabbar element so that when the tabbar buttons are pressed it loads each view as that of the tabbar controller. Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: I have posted an answer...accept and voted it if it is helpful to u..:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For fliping the view, implement this..

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL]; 
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.80];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight 
                       forView:self.navigationController.view cache:NO];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:self.detailviewcontyrollerObj animated:YES];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

And u want tabbar from second view, so in first view'a button click(or anything else), write code for calling function from app delegate..

```
-(IBAction)clickme
{
AppDelegate *app = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
[app SwitchToTabbarController];
}
```

Now, in app delegate, declare method named SwitchToTabbarController, in which implement this..

```
 _tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
FirstViewController *view1 = [[FirstViewController alloc] init];
SecondViewController *view2 = [[SecondViewController alloc]init];

UINavigationController *tbl1=[[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:view1] autorelease];
tbl1.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;

tbl1.navigationBarHidden=NO;    

UINavigationController *tbl2=[[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:view2] autorelease];
tbl2.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;

tbl2.navigationBarHidden=NO;
 _tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:tbl1,tbl2,nil];

[_window addSubview:_tabBarController.view];   
self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
[_window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Implement as whole will be much helpful and I think that is what u want....:)